# Mouse clicks after movement

Tags: mouse

I have had a problem since I installed 10.10 on my laptop.  I now run 11.4.

When I move the mouse cursor, it clicks a couple seconds after I come to a rest.  I can move the mouse, throw my hands up in  the air, and the cursor will click where ever it is pointing.  This makes typing a real pain, even typing this the mouse put my text cursor in different places.

I thought this was a problem with my physical mouse pad, but I used a external usb mouse and I did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

With *Assistive Technologies* we are able to initiate a mouse click when mouse pointer movements stop. To disable this go to *System Settings* and open *Control Center -> Assistive Technologies*:

[image]

From there choose *Mouse Accessibility*:

[image]

Untick the option *"Initiate click when stopping mouse pointer movement"*.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using ubuntu 14.04 or later, i could access that by going to *system settings > universal access* then click on the ***Pointing and clicking*** tab , turn **[hover click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk5gh.png)** off